# Xcode tabbed application show second UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

We have a question about `XCode` tabbed application.
We created a App with tabbed application with 3 tab bar items.

1. One tabbar item is just an button and a viewcontroller with a
   `imageview` (the button is in the tabbar).
2. The second tabbar item connects through a navigation controller to a
   `UITableViewcontroller` which connects to a seconds
   `UITableViewcontroller`. In the first `UITableViewcontroller` we have a
   list of products and the second `UITableViewcontroller` is a list with
   details of an product select in de the first UITableViewcontroller.
3. When the user tabs the button (step 1) on the tabbar we want to go
   to the second UITableView in step 2.

So we want to skip the first `UITableViewcontroller`.
Is this possible to do programmatically ?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, it is possible.

1. If you are using `UITabBarController`, you can use `selectedIndex` property to set which is the displayed `UIViewController`. Read more about managing `UITabBarController` here:

   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html
2. If you are using only `UITabBar` view, it has a property called `selectedItem` and you provide your second tab bar item. So wire your button to update the `UITabBar` property correctly and push the second `UITableViewController` on navigation stack. Read more about `UITabBar` here:

   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html
3. Start using `UITabBarController`, it is created especially for cases like yours.

**Read more about navigation in iOS:**

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html

Comment: We have a custom class for the tabbarcontroller , the mid tabbaritem (selectedindex 1) is a UIButton.
When this button is clicked i want to go directly to the selectedindex (0)tabbaritem which contains: navigationcontroller > tableviewcontroller > tableviewcontroller and i want to go directly to the last tableviewcontroller.